# Are there any real-world SharpKit Applications?

Tags: c#, javascript, translation

We're evaluating [SharpKit](http://sharpkit.net/) as a possible technology to write an AJAX application, as we already have much C# code that we believe will work well after translating to JavaScript.

We're aware of ScriptSharp and other related technologies - there are many Stack Overflow threads about them, and this question is specifically about SharpKit only.

We have several concerns, hence are looking for real world experiences with SharpKit. In particular:

1. The one app built using SharpKit is the coderun IDE. While impressive, it is just one app, and a closed source one at that.
2. There are apparently no good app-sized sample projects built on SharpKit.
3. The SharpKit documentation is extremely poor - no in-depth conceptual overviews or tutorials, just a few 5 minute videos and a class library. (When will toolkit vendors learn that a generated class reference maketh not a user guide?)
4. There is no forum - so we can't determine how much this toolkit is actually being used. For all we know, this is a barely supported project written by three guys. What has your support experience been like?
5. There is no phone contact or support - which again raises a red flag regarding support.

Please don't respond with ScriptSharp or other information - we're just trying to evaluate SharpKit here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Check out [DesktopBrowser](http://desktopbrowser.googlecode.com), an open-source project that uses SharpKit.
2. See #1
3. There's also an MSDN style reference for all internal and external libraries, you can find it [here](http://sharpkit.net/help/).
4. Check out 'SharpKit Support' forum at google groups.
5. Contacting support is initially done by email at support@sharpkit.net.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks - DesktopBrowser is a very simple application. Since there are no more complex apps, we're not going to use SharpKit at this time.

Comment: What about http://www.coderun.com/? :)